# How to call functions or access public mappings from inside of a subgraph?

Tags: tokens, nft, events, the-graph, subgraph

I have this struct and mapping inside my smart-contract:

```
struct attrStruct {
    uint256 generation;
    string faction;
}

mapping(uint256 => attrStruct) public attributes;
```

I want to fetch and store new version of this struct ( they get modified on-chain in normal transactions ). How can I use something like `await contract.attributes(tokenId)` inside my subgraph?

**Mapping.ts**

```
export function handleTransfer(event: TransferEvent): void {
    let token = Token.load(event.params.tokenId.toString())
    if (!token) {
        token = new Token(event.params.tokenId.toString())
        // What to write here to fetch the struct?
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you probably have only access to the data of the event (from, to, tokenId) and not the state of the blockchain at that event. If you can get the block number, then you could use web3js library to ask an *Archive* node about attributes in that block

Comment: Thank you, I ended up creating 2 new events to broadcast specific changes. I just expected the contract to be available to query the same way `event.block` is made available to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.bind` contract

Uniswap V3 subgraph has an example here: https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-subgraph/blob/bf03f940f17c3d32ee58bd37386f26713cff21e2/src/mappings/core.ts#L402-L404

```
 let poolContract = PoolABI.bind(event.address) // bind the contract ABI to the address
 let feeGrowthGlobal0X128 = poolContract.feeGrowthGlobal0X128() // call method feeGrowthGlobal0X128()
 let feeGrowthGlobal1X128 = poolContract.feeGrowthGlobal1X128() // call method feeGrowthGlobal1X128()
```